# OpenGL faulty rendering after Arch linux update

Tags: linux, arch-linux, graphics, opengl

I am working on a Dell Optioplex 7010 with intel Core i5 vPro running Arch linux. I did a regular OS update to version 5.11.9-arch1-1 recently (April 2021) and noticed that anything that uses OpenGL shows incomplete filling of surfaces such that you get multiple 'see through' triangles and rectangles. This picture illustrates the problem:
[X-screen saver geodesic gears showing the OpenGL problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4wbq.png)
Any ideas how to diagnose and fix this problem?

Here is what i have tried so far:

- Looking at different software to see if it was an issue with a particular package. Result: This is not limited to the X-Screen saver or any particular software package - the same corruption occurs in Cura, FreeCAD, etc. anything that uses openGL.
- Manually overriding the mesa loader driver using 'export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE' but none of the available drivers made a difference to the problem.
- Check my graphics card status. Result:

> ```
> $ sudo lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
> ```

```
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0152] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])


    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
     Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0577]
     Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
     Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
     Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
     I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
     Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
     Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
     Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
     Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
     Kernel driver in use: i915
     Kernel modules: i915
```

- Check my OpenGL status. Result:

> ```
> $ sudo glxinfo | grep OpenGL
> OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
> OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 2500 (IVB GT1)
> OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.3.4
> OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
> OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
> OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
> OpenGL core profile extensions:
> OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.3.4
> OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
> OpenGL context flags: (none)
> OpenGL extensions:
> OpenGL ES profile version string:
> OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 20.3.4
> OpenGL ES profile shading language version string:
> OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
> OpenGL ES profile extensions:
> ```

Everything was working fine before the OS update. I can't see an error or anything to fix in the above. Any help appreciated.

[EDIT - in response to comments]

I also checked the pacman log to see what packages were changed or added in the last -Syyu update. I found the following which I thought might have something to do with the OpenGL graphics rendering:

- installed box2d (2.4.1-1)
- installed gts (0.7.6.121130-2)
- upgraded intel-media-driver (20.4.5-1 -> 21.1.2-1)
- upgraded glslang (11.1.0-1 -> 11.2.0-3)
- upgraded gegl (0.4.26-1 -> 0.4.28-2)
- upgraded gd (2.3.0-1 -> 2.3.2-2)
- upgraded mesa (20.3.3-1 -> 20.3.4-3)

So I downgraded the packages that were upgraded (one-by-one, rebooting after each) and uninstalled the newly installed packages with `pacman -Rsc`. Unfortunately none of this fixed the issue.

Comment: What were all of the packages involved in the update? (Check `/var/log/pacman.log`.) The version you mentioned only describes the kernel; it doesn't really say anything about Mesa OpenGL or the rest.

Comment: @user1686 Thanks for the tip - I looked at the log and edited my post with the new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also sought help for this from the Arch forum. Thanks to a post there I found the answer. It turns out that I needed to set a kernel parameter for the i915 module. Specifically: `i915.mitigations=off`
(in my setup is was set to 'auto' previously).
When I appended this kernel parameter to my
`/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf`
file and rebooted, The problem no longer existed.
No idea why this suddenly became necessary when it was working fine before.